Custom theory of atoms in z3
I would like to have some variables in z3 that takes values in some infinite set, whose elements have no operations except equality comparisons (the theory of atoms in the sense of lisp). Currently I'm simply encoding the values by strings, but then z3 may assign ill-formed strings which I want to avoid, and I'm worried that the other operations on strings might be an overhead for the solver.
I have a relation P(x, y, z) on this set that, given two of the variables, have only finitely many possibilities for the other variable. An example might be x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 0 mod 10000, but in my case it is much more complex and I don't think it is convenient to encode or axiomatize the relation directly into z3. So I'm planning to write a custom propagator that adds in implication clauses like "x = "a" and z = "b" implies y = "ab" or y = "ba"" whenever x and z gets assigned. Is this the right way to go? Or is this type of problems better solved by something else?

If all you care about is equality, then uninterpreted sorts is the way to go. But then you state an arithmetic relationship: Are these actually numbers? Please clarify.

@alias That is an unrelated example to demonstrate "finitely many possibilities".

If all you need is equality, then EUF (equality with uninterpreted functions) is the way to go. Here's a nice write up: https://www21.in.tum.de/teaching/sar/SS20/6.pdf
Almost all SMT solvers support EUF, and it has a decidable theory. Do not complicate your models with strings or any other datatype when all you care about is equality on atoms. EUF is precisely the logic you should be using.
Regarding your relation P: It really depends on what kind of relation this is. You can have simple axioms about it, and they'd go through fine. If you have quantified axioms, then you'll be in the semi-decidable fragment. It really all depends on what P needs to satisfy. (There's also custom support in z3 for transitive closures, if that's something you care about. But without seeing details of your problem, it's hard to opine if it would apply.)

This mostly works for my purposes. Is there a way to make the consequences interface also work? I.e. I have a (potentially infinite) special set of mutually distinct constants, and I would like the consequences function to determine the variables that are equal to one of these constants in every model. With strings I can just use string literals for them, but it's not obvious what to do when they are uninterpreted constants.

I don't see why you can't do that with uninterpreted sorts. But it's hard to talk in abstract: Please post a minimal-example of what you tried and what didn't work, as a separate question so it can be discussed. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
